# Can't understand this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @date varchar(30) =  '2013-04-18'

DECLARE @WeekOfMonth TINYINT
SET @WeekOfMonth = 
    (
      DAY(@DATE) + 
      (DATEPART(dw, 
                DATEADD (MONTH, 
                         DATEDIFF (MONTH, 
                                   0, 
                                   @DATE),
                         0)) 
       - 1) -1) / 7 + 1

print @WeekOfMonth
```

This is a query I found over the internet to find out **week number of the month** like it's '2013-03-04' today and this is **second** week of this month, Query is working fine, But I can't understand it and the person who has posted it over that blog haven't described it's working either. Can someone please help me to understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's calculating the week number of the month, by adding the **day number** to the **weekday number of the first day of that month**, then divide by 7 and add 1. For example, with '2013-03-04', the day number is 4, the week number of '2013-03-01' is 6 (Friday), so the result is (4 + 6 - 1 - 1)/7 + 1 = 2.

Working from the inside out:

(DAY('2013-03-04') + (DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(MONTH, **DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '2013-03-04')**, 0)) - 1) - 1) / 7 + 1

- Number of months from 1900-01-01, 1358

(DAY('2013-03-04') + (DATEPART(dw, **DATEADD(MONTH, 1358, 0)**) - 1) - 1) / 7 + 1

- The date that is 1358 months from 1900-01-01, 2013-03-01

(DAY('2013-03-04') + (**DATEPART(dw, '2013-03-01')** - 1) - 1) / 7 + 1

- Day of week of '2013-03-01', 6 (Friday)

(**DAY('2013-03-04')** + (6 - 1) - 1) / 7 + 1

- The day part of '2013-03-04', 4

(4 + (6 **- 1**) - 1) / 7 + 1

- -1 to convert Sunday = day 1 to Monday = day 1

(4 + 5 **- 1**) / 7 + 1

- -1 because '2013-03-04' is 3 days from '2013-03-01'

= 2

Comment: So `1970-01-01` is the smallest date value in SQL ? I didn't understand this part `-1 because '2013-03-04' is 3 days from '2013-03-01'` as '2013-03-04' is a dynamic value.

Comment: I get 1900-01-01 as the base date

Comment: *‘…by adding the **day number** to the **week number of the first day of that month** …’* – actually, the former is added to the **weekday number** (`dw`) of the first day of the month. Also, the "0" date in SQL Server is indeed `1900-01-01`, as @DanMetheus has correctly noted. (1358 months is 100+ years, so "0" can't possibly stand for `1970-01-01`)

Comment: Thanks @yogi and everyone, forgot that SQL date starts at 1900-01-01. Also, the last point means to get the number of days from the first day of the month given a day number, you need to subtract 1, since the 1st of the month is 0 days from the 1st of the month, and not 1. Hard to explain in text only and I wasn't trying to over-explain.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of looking at this:

You can run these statements to break it down yourself:

```
select datediff(month, 0, getdate()); -- Get Months since 1900-01-01
select DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, getdate()),0); -- Add Months back to 1900-01-01 to get 1st of Month (essentially stripping time and days)
select DATEPART(dw,DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, getdate()),0)-1); Get Day of Week Number for 1st of Current Month
select (day(getdate()) + DATEPART(dw,DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, getdate()),0)-1)-1); -- Add Day Number of Month for Current Date then subtract 1 to make it days, since we started on 1st
select (day(getdate()) + DATEPART(dw,DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, getdate()),0)-1)-1)/7; -- Determine how many whole weeks can be divided into this result
select (day(getdate()) + (DATEPART(dw,DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, getdate()),0))-1)-1)/7+1; -- We're zero indexed (meaning results would be zero in 1st week), so add 1 to get week number
```